# Searching element in a grid in ext.js in pagination

Tags: extjs, pagination, datagrid

I have implemented pagination in my grid in ext.js. In some scenarios, I need to pick a value from my grid which is on another page based on id which is unique for each record. When I try to fetch from the store it only gives me 20 records of the current page. How do I get a record from the grid with my id going through all pages or any shortcut?

Comment: Depends on your implementation, version of ExtJs and toolkit. Provide some sample in fiddle..

Comment: Your store is paginated, it means your server will return only one page at a time, in your case 20 records. I would suggest to do this kind of filtering on the server side and set `remoteFilter: true` on your store.

Comment: Or you have to go with local pagination to catch all data at once (which might not get you the benefit of less data send from the server)